# Bluetooth audio multipoint via PC or phone as a2dp

Tags: ubuntu, audio, android, bluetooth, a2dp

I have bluetooth headphones, which I would like to connect to my PC and phone at the same time. However, only multipoint devices are capable of this. I was wondering, if I can make either my phone or my PC to act like a A2DP sink and source to channel audio from the other device to my headphones?

e.g. My [phone]/[PC] is connected to my headphones and sends audio to them. Then my [PC is connected to my phone]/[phone is connected to my PC] and sends audio to it. The receiving end routes that audio to my headphones.

Is this somehow possible? I was thinking that tiny headphones lack the computational power to do this (unless they are multipoint). But phone/PC has plenty of power to achieve this.

I am using Ubuntu and Android.

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: There are apps and services that play phone audio over your PC. Also, I've bought 2 Bluetooth headsets, an active pair, and a nice set of noise canceling 'phones, and both supported 2 simultaneous device connection. Multipoint doesn't cost more, you just need to look for the feature.

Comment: @music2myear I bought some and turned out to be wrongly labeled on a giant internet site (You know what). The ones I have found were 2x or more expensive.

Comment: I personally own the Plantronics Backbeat Fit (an older model) and the Backbeat Pro (newer model) and both were competitively priced for Bluetooth headsets and both connect 2 devices simultaneously. However, this site is not for recommending hardware, and the easiest solution to your problem is to use an app that enables streaming device audio to your PC. Anything else is more complex than it is worth, and is attempting to reinvent the wheel.